# I can't feed my horse. What do I do?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I managed to get a horse to like me. That's swell. But I can't seem to figure out how to feed the horse. I right clicked on the horse and tamed it. No feeding was involved.

I have some wheat in my hand. Right click and I'm riding horse. Left click and I beat horse with wheat, leading to dismay and confusion on both our parts.

Tried the "mob effects" button but that doesn't let me feed the horse.

Tried searching, and all the results I get just tell me to give the horse wheat. That's not my problem. My problem is that when I try I end up smacking my horse in the face with wheat. The horse don't like it. He goes all red and runs away.

Exactly how (like what random key mapping on the pc) do I use to feed the horse? I am playing on PC, the Windows 10 version of Minecraft.

Comment: Can you please order your thoughts before writing them down? Your writing, not talking, so if you want to correct something, correct what you already wrote and try to give a concise explanation of your problem. Secondly, the wiki is your friend. It tells you what horses eat. Thirdly, do you play in "Windows 10 edition"? You used the Java edition tag, but the last line makes it sound like that's not what you play.

Comment: If you ever post any more questions / answers on this site please try to keep the post short (if possible) and to the point. It's fine to joke around a little but you could probably some up this 5 paragraph question in 3 sentences. Also like Fabian said use the wikis. I was able to find the answer with one search and about 5 seconds on the page.

Answer (score 4):

Horses will only eat when they are missing health.

Sugar - Heals 0.5

Hearts Wheat - Heals 1 Heart

Apples - Heals 1.5 Hearts

Golden Carrot - Heals 5 Hearts

Golden Apples - Heals 5 Hearts

Enchanted Golden Apple - Heals 5 Hearts

Hay Bale - Heals 10 Hearts

[Source](https://www.digminecraft.com/getting_started/how_to_feed_horse.php)

Answer (score 0):

Are you definitely trying to feed [Wheat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat) to the Horse?

Is it definitely [Tamed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse#Taming)?

*Feeding invalid food causes the player to mount the horse*(1)

(1) [Feeding a Horse](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse#Food)

I usually use a Hay Bale - but only if the Horse doesn't have full health!